# How to use ref keyword for .Value

Tags: c#

I have a simple bit of code where i check the position of my mouse and if it is not null, i snap the position to a particular place.

The problem is, i can't seem to pass the value to the method. The code looks like this:

```
        Vector3? T = Mouse.WorldPosition;
        if (T != null)
        {
            FindSnapPoint(ref T.Value); //property or indexer may not be passed
        }
```

Why is this not allowed? And what can I do to fix this problem, i don't use a return since i use this method in a lot of places and it makes it a lot more elegant if i `ref` the value.

Is my only option here to revert to returning a Vector3 rather than using `ref`?

Comment: Well that doesn't really explain what the solution is all that clearly.. other than i guess make another Vector3 ? If i make my own then i have to use `out` and that breaks all the rest of my code where i am not passing nullables.

Comment: Even if you did chose to use a return value, you also wouldn't be able to write `T.Value = FindSnapPoint()` since `Value` is read-only. That should make it obvious why you can't expect it to be written through a ref parameter either.

Comment: Short answer; indexers and properties are implemented as methods under the hood. Thus, you cannot pass a *reference* to the value, since it's actually retrieved by invoking a method.

Comment: So i would be better off just doing a normal return of a Vector3 ?

Comment: Without knowing more context: yes, it is generally advisable to avoid ref/out parameters. If you really want to keep your method as it is, you could introduce a local `Vector3` variable, initialize it with `T.Value` and pass that as argument. But remember that this won't immediately change the value of `T`.